# QuickOSM using Wild Cards / RegEx

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api, regular-expression, quickosm

Can someone explain to me how to use wild cards with QuickOSM? I'm trying to match all shops with a name starting with a specific word (e.g. Costco).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to the `Query` panel and write your own query such as:

```
[out:xml][timeout:25];
(
  nwr["name"~"Costco(.*)"]
  ["shop"]
  ({{bbox}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

or in XML format, so QuickOSM will be able to highlight it correctly:

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="25">
    <union>
        <query type="nwr">
            <has-kv k="shop"/>
            <has-kv k="name" regv="Costco(.*)"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
    </union>
    <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```

Both queries work in the plugin. It the same.

QuickOSM is using the Overpass API language:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Key.2Fvalue_matches_regular_expression_.28.7E.22key_regex.22.7E.22value_regex.22.29