# Wildcard in QuickOSM name tag

Tags: qgis, overpass-api, quickosm

I'm looking to map (for the sake of the example) all memorials to Lincoln in California using QGIS' QuickOSM plugin.

The query I can easily set up

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
 {{geocodeArea:California}} -> .area_0;
(
    node["memorial"]["name"="Lincoln"](area.area_0);
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

looks for the exact match in the name tag. As a result, QuickOSM returns me the message `Successful query, but no result`, even though California definitely has a memorial with "Lincoln" in the name (the "[Abraham Lincoln War Memorial](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/3931251688)" in Oakland, at least).

**How do I formulate the query so that it only checks if the name tag contains this string?**

I found a [feature request](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/59) on Github for Overpass API, and a discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87871/qgis-select-features-from-attribute-table-using-the-like-operator) proposing to use "LIKE", which is however apparently not working for QuickOSM:

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
 {{geocodeArea:California}} -> .area_0;
(
    node["memorial"]["name" LIKE "%Lincoln%"](area.area_0);

);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

returns
`Bad request OverpassAPI.`

Comment: If it it close to plain SQL then try `"'%Lincoln%'"`.

Comment: Your first query doesn't return any data if you copy/paste in https://overpass-turbo.eu/ as well which is using the same database in the backend. I haven't debug your query, maybe you are not in the correct "geocoded area".

Comment: @etrimaille Yes exactly, because this is the syntax for an exact match in the name tag. If I change the query to include the full name (i.e. "name"="Abraham Lincoln War Memorial"), then both QuickOSM and overpass-turbo.eu return one result (that one in Oakland). My question is about how I can search for a partial match in the name tag.

Comment: @user30184 When I try this in QuickOSM or overpass-turbo.eu, I get the same message ("Successful query, but no result"), so it seems the % symbol doesn't act as a wildcard in this case.

Comment: Sorry, the question was maybe not clear

Comment: Please have a look to existing questions : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338036/quickosm-using-wild-cards-regex/338051#338051 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367674/quickosm-using-wild-cards-on-lines-rivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be relatively simple: it's sufficient to replace the `=` with a `~`. This apparently looks for partial matches.

Using the original example:

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
 {{geocodeArea:California}} -> .area_0;
(
    node["memorial"]["name" ~ "Lincoln"](area.area_0);
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

now successfully returns three memorials to Lincoln in California, including the one in Oakland.